# How to change contextMenu default mouse button?

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, contextmenu

I have a contextMenu and I added it to a button. I want the contextMenu to be displayed when I left-click(PRIMARY) on the button. How can I do this? Because by default just right-clicking does this.

I tried this way but it did not work

```
Button sortBy = new Button();

ContextMenu sortByMenu = new ContextMenu();
    sortByMenu.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, ev -> {
        if (ev.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
            //does not do anything
        }
    });

 sortBy.setContextMenu(sortByMenu);
```

Comment: why did you edit your question without applying my last comment? Plus: why do you expect any node/window to react to mouseEvents if it's not showing? Anyway, [mcve] required - it should demonstrate what you are _really_ after and how it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MenuButton**

> [`MenuButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) is a button which, when clicked or pressed, will show a `ContextMenu`.

Example code from the javadoc:

```
MenuButton m = new MenuButton(
    "Eats"
);
m.getItems().addAll(
    new MenuItem("Burger"),
    new MenuItem("Hot Dog")
);
```

**ChoiceBox**

You could also consider a [ChoiceBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/choice-box.htm), depending on what you are trying to do.

> The [`ChoiceBox`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html) is used for presenting the user with a relatively small set of predefined choices from which they may choose.

```
ChoiceBox<String> cb = new ChoiceBox<>();
cb.getItems().addAll(
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3"
);
```

To select a sortBy sorting field from a list of choices, a ChoiceBox would probably be a good fit.